# $scope or $http vs. response or reason in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I started learning Angular JS two hours ago and saw this in the tutorial:

```
var app = angular.module("githubViewer", []);

var MainController = function($scope, $http){

    var onUserComplete = function(response){
        $scope.user = response.data;
    };
    var onError = function(reason){
        $scope.error = "Failed to get the user info.";
    };

    var promise = $http.get("https://api.github.com/users/someone");
    promise.then(onUserComplete, onError);

};

app.controller("MainController", MainController);
```

I understand $scope/$http is native to Angular but what about the response/reason? How are they passed to the function?

Comment: And yes, I am not familiar with Javascript itself.

Answer (score 0):

Those are the callback functions - `onUserComplete` and `onError`, which are called when the promise returned by `$http.get()` function is resolved. The callback functions are passed response returned by the completion of `$http.get()` invocation. The parameter in the function is that response.

Answer (score 0):

@Rohit Jain is right.

This is much more a related to Javascript then Angular.

CallBack are often used in JS.

Here is a quick exemple to understand how CallBack works

```
function mainFunc(mycallBack){
  mycallBack()
}

function onSomething(){
  alert("hi");
}
mainFunc(onSomething);
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/Ud1E6Wbns1EnItVI8Xg7?p=preview

I hope it helps.

Regards,
Eric